# Why the same ID is being repeated for all the items

Tags: jquery

Could anybody please tell me why the same id is being printed for all the items ??

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                    var undefined = "something";
                 var obj = new Object();

                 var responseinner = [{
                     "id": "59",
                     "has_topping": "1",
                     "price": "75"
                 }, {
                     "id": "60",
                     "has_topping": "1",
                     "price": "75"
                 }];


                 Object.size = function (obj) {
                     var size = 0,
                         key;
                     for (key in obj) {
                         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
                     }
                     return size;
                 };


                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     var size = Object.size(responseinner[0]);
                     for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                         var v_item_id = responseinner[0].id;
                         alert(v_item_id);
                     }
                 });
    </script>
```

Comment: What output do you expect? What's the purpose of the code?

Comment: *"Why the same ID is being repeated for all the items"* Because you are always accessing the same value: `responseinner[0].id` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code, `responseinner` is an array which consist of objects. So we can iterate it directly and fetch the desired result from the objects.

Try,

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner.length; i++) {
   var v_item_id = responseinner[i].id;
   alert(v_item_id);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jr35V/)